# Error: Refused to display 'https://beta.app.com' in a frame because it set > 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try display the page in `<iframe>` in `popup.html`. but I have error:

> Refused to display 'https://beta.app.com' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

**popup.html**

```
<div id="app-container">
    <iframe width="500" height="500" src="https://beta.app.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @xOxxOm  Where should I set it: `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener`? In `content.js`?

Comment: No, in the popup script. Content scripts can't access most of API.